# Is Pinax alive?

Tags: django, pinax

I've seen [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) in the past and I'd like to use it today. It's on version 0.7. I wonder know if it's still in development.

Comment: Very nice thingie... I learned something new. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very alive, as you can see in its [GitHub repository](http://github.com/pinax/pinax/)

Comment: Its undocumented however... :-(

Comment: Landed here in 2021.... Can I ask for an update for this?  Does pinax work on django 2 or 3 ? It seems outdated now...

Answer (score 3):

It's very much under active development.  Check out http://groups.google.com/group/pinax-users for the latest info.

Answer (score 0):

An important note:

Much of Pinax is Django-apps which are **developed separately from pinax** and are brought in via version control systems (subversion, mercurial, git, etc)

So **even if** the pinax project maintainers were to go on a 6 month hiatus (though they are very unlikely to), the platform would **continue to be updated and receive bug fixes**